# Как используется пространство имён tools в XML?

Tags: android, xml

Подскажите для чего используется пространство имён `tools` в XML-разметке?

`xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

Пример: `tools:uiLayout="..."`

Comment: Вот тут подробно расписано http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/studio/tools.php

Comment: @АндройдАндройд Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В двух словах - применив к элементу атрибут в этом пространстве имён вместо привычного "android", вы увидите эффект в режиме предпросмотра, но на реальном устройстве или эмуляторе при дебаге ничего не изменится. Удобно использовать для заполнения текстовых болванок, когда хотелось бы посмотреть, как оно будет выглядеть на самом деле, а хардкодить сам текст в XML-разметке не хорошо.

```
tools:text="Тестовый текст"
```

Тоже самое можно делать с цветами, да и ещё много с чем. [Здесь](http://tools.android.com/tips/layout-designtime-attributes) про это неплохо написано.